# Extracting code to put it in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I have the following working js/jquery code :

```
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
  return $('.datetime_field').datetimepicker({
  altField: '#datetime_to_server',
  altFormat: 'yy-m-d',
  altFieldTimeOnly: false,
  altTimeFormat: 'hh:mm:00'
}); 
})
```

The whole function event is also called elsewhere :

```
(function() {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    return $('.datetime_field').datetimepicker({
      altField: '#datetime_to_server',
      altFormat: 'yy-m-d',
      altFieldTimeOnly: false,
      altTimeFormat: 'hh:mm:00'
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

I want to extract the identical code and call him. Problem is that i tried but I can make it work. How can i extract the similar code and call it from those two different places?

EDIT : I tried this :

```
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', refresh_datetime_listener())

function refresh_datetime_listener(){
return $('.datetime_field').datetimepicker({
  altField: '#datetime_to_server',
  altFormat: 'yy-m-d',
  altFieldTimeOnly: false,
  altTimeFormat: 'hh:mm:00'
}); 
}
```

But it says datetimepicker is not a function.

Comment: How did you tried ? It's not clear why you couldn't simply declare a function.

Comment: Regarding your edit: `on` expects a *function*, but you are giving it the *result of a function* (which happens to be a `jQuery` object here). The `()` at the end of your function mean "call `refresh_datetime_listener` and pass its return value to `on`". Thus, when it come time to fire the event, `on` tries to call a `jQuery` object as a function, which unsurprisingly fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @dystroy, have you tried

```
function myFunc(event){
  return $('.datetime_field').datetimepicker({
  altField: '#datetime_to_server',
  altFormat: 'yy-m-d',
  altFieldTimeOnly: false,
  altTimeFormat: 'hh:mm:00'
}); 
}
```

then

```
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', myFunc);
```

and

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(myFunc);
}).call(this);
```

Note that the event bindings are passed function references, and not function calls. `myFunc`, and not `myFunc()`